# How to query mongodb to build brought together items using purchase history

Tags: javascript, mongodb

MongoDB noob here. Please bear with me for the long post, I am trying to include most of the information.

I have the following document structure (includes only relevant fields) for a single order, and there are many orders like this which I export from an SQL database.

**From these documents, I want to find out the frequently brought together items for a given `product_id`. where `product_id` is a field nested inside `order_summary->products`**

```
{
  "_id": "5d9de7fbbcd759252825b182",
  "order_id": 100000,
  "user_id": 9425,
  "order_summary": {
    "products": [
      {
        "name": {
          "en": "Product A"
        },
        "price": "2.400",
        "quantity": 2,
        "product_id": 100,
        "variant_id": 98
      },
      {
        "name": {
          "en": "Product B"
        },
        "price": "3.900",
        "quantity": 1,
        "product_id": 401,
        "variant_id": 395
      }
    ]
  },
  "total": "16.895"
}
```

Basically I would like to achieve the following

- Given a product id -> get all the orders contains that product_id
- From the orders take all the other product_ids in those orders
- group the `product_id` together with `sum` of the quantity
- return the result set ordered by the `sum` of quantity

I was successful querying Mongo DB on the root fields, But when it comes to querying the nested fields I am getting null (Probably an error internally) most of the time.

So far I was able to set up the following, but the result is not exactly what I want

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    orderCollection = db.collection('orders');
    orderCollection.aggregate([
        { $match: {"order_summary.products.product_id": 100} }, // 100 is the product_id I want to match with
        { $group: { 
            _id: "$order_summary.products.product_id", 
            total: {$sum: "$order_summary.products.quantity"}
          }
        }
    ]).toArray(function (err, docs) {

        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

The result I get

```
Found the following records
[
  { _id: [ 100, 937 ], total: 0 },
  { _id: [ 70, 100, 209, 1338, 8572 ], total: 0 },
  { _id: [ 100, 401, 754 ], total: 0 },
  { _id: [ 100, 401, 705, 8134 ], total: 0 },
  { _id: [ 100, 705, 942 ], total: 0 },
  { _id: [ 100, 670 ], total: 0 }
]
```

The Result I expect

```
[
  {_id: 100, total: 150},
  {_id: 70, total: 140},
  {_id: 401, total: 135},
  .....
  {_id: 670, total: 1},
]
```

I am using `mongodb": "^3.3.2`, Javascript client and mongodb `MongoDB 4.0.12 Community, Let me know if any more information needs to be posted

Comment: You need to unwind the products array before grouping and summing.
But still your requirement and the result you want doesn't look same?

Comment: Nope, becase as you can see the total was always zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will give your expected result.

```
[{$unwind: {
  path:"$order_summary.products"
}}, {$group: {
  _id: "$order_summary.products.product_id",
 total: {$sum: "$order_summary.products.quantity"}
}}]
```

Below is the result

```
{
    "_id" : 670.0,
    "total" : 4.0
},
{
    "_id" : 70.0,
    "total" : 24.0
},
{
    "_id" : 100.0,
    "total" : 10.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I put the match query? When I put the $match as shown in the question I am getting a Null result

Comment: you can add $match as first stage in the pipeline.